# Creating Stored procedures in MySql/phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have already created my database with tables and now I want to create stored procedures for my tables but I keep getting an error.

This is how I try creating the stored procedure in SQL:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_accesslevel_Select() 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM accesslevel; 
END // 
DELIMITER;
```

And the error I get is:

"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_accesslevel_Select() 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM ' at line 1 "

Can anyone help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to go in "Routines" menu and create it from there

Comment: Im using apache phpmyadmin and there is no Routine there.

Comment: I saw the link, but unfortunately Im using the apache installed in my university and its apache2.2 and it doesnt have Routine option

Comment: I don't think Apache have any thing to do with phpmyadmin, do you access it like this? http://localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: yes I do, and then I open my database and there is no option for routine

Comment: then you have to do it like this http://i.imgur.com/4OwaHwN.jpg don't forget to change delimiter like in the image in down left